# Jquery show or hide a specific element

Tags: jquery, html

Hello i am trying to show/hide a specific element with the same id or class like others.

```
<span id="showimg">Zobrazit přílohu</span>
<span id="hideimg">Skrýt přílohu</span>
<div class="images-con">
</div>

<span id="showimg">Zobrazit přílohu</span>
<span id="hideimg">Skrýt přílohu</span>
<div class="images-con">
</div>
```

So when i click on first button id=showimg first div will be shown, but not both of them. Any ideas how should i solve my problem?

Comment: Well the first step towards solving any problem is making an attempt to solve it on your own before asking for help.

Comment: I know how to hide/show div. But how to show first or second div? Not both at the same time

Comment: Well, as a nudge in the right direction, element IDs *must be **unique***. But you should do some research on `$(this)`, which will only effect the element that is clicked.

Comment: Are you sure it must be unique. There is no more options?

Comment: [I am very sure it must be unique](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute), however you can use something like a *class* on multiple elements. You can then put a click event on that class, and use `$(this)` to target the specific element that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine two or more people with the same social security number... it would be a mess, wouldn't it?! The same applies to ***ID*** → **it must be unique-per-page**.

Use classes. Or even better use `data-*` attributes to reference a desired target like:

```js
var $toggle    = $("[data-toggle]");    // Collect all buttons
var $togglable = $("[data-togglable]"); // Collect all containers
var btnText = ["↑ Skrýt přílohu","↓ Zobrazit přílohu"];


$toggle.on("click", function(){ // The toggle buttons...

  // Get my data value
  var data =  this.dataset.toggle;
  // I should target the container which data value matches mine
  var $target = $("[data-togglable='"+ data +"']");
  // Now let's handle the buttons texts:
  // Show the opening text to all buttons (I'll handle my-self soon)
  $toggle.not( this ).text( btnText[1] );
  // Toggle my text
  $("[data-toggle='"+ data +"']").text( btnText[+$target.is(":visible")] );
  

  // Hide all opened containers (ignore my target container, I'll handle him soon)
  $togglable.not( $target ).stop().slideUp();
  // Toggle my target container
  $target.stop().slideToggle();
  
});
```

```css
/* BUTTONS */
a[data-toggle] {
  border-top: 1px solid #444;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 16px; 
  background: #0bf;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a[data-toggle] .hideimg{
  display: none; /* hide "Skrýt přílohu" initially */
}

/* CONTENTS */
.images-con{
  display:none; /* hide all DIVs initially */
  padding: 8px 16px; 
  background: #bf0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a data-toggle="div1">&darr; Zobrazit přílohu</a>
<div data-togglable="div1" class="images-con">Hi! I'm div1</div>


<a data-toggle="div2">&darr; Zobrazit přílohu</a>
<div data-togglable="div2" class="images-con">Hello♪ It's me...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JQuery, assign every button the same class and try this:

```
$(".whateveryourclass").click(function() {

    $(this).toggle();

});
```

Comment: @Santi Good point - I made the change. I'd normally agree with you on the fact that it shouldn't have been answered, except I don't actually know if the OP has tried it or not. Looks like his/her English isn't the best and they are new to S/O so it was such a simple answer, I figured I'd help out.

Comment: I understand what did you post, but its actually not what im looking for. I need something like if i click on for example first #showimg it will show first div and when i click on second the same will happen but with second div. I hope you understand me

Comment: @JakubStaněk But how do you actually know which ```showimg``` to show? You should second guess the architecture of the app. Something doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 0):

So finally i made it. I changed showimg/hideimg from id to class. This solved my problem.

```
$(".showimg").click(function(){
    $(this).parents(".images-gallery").find("div.images-con").show()
    $(this).parents(".images-gallery").find(".hideimg").show()
    $(this).parents(".images-gallery").find(".showimg").hide()
});

$(".hideimg").click(function(){
    $(this).parents(".images-gallery").find("div.images-con").hide()
    $(this).parents(".images-gallery").find(".showimg").show()
    $(this).parents(".images-gallery").find(".hideimg").hide()
});
```

Comment: Where's `images-gallery` in your provided Question code?